# Why DBMS_METADATA.GET_DLL not work with EXEC command ?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Using Oracle 11g

I just trying to understand the concept here....
Why the command bellow not work? (executed at SQL Developer)

```
execute dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'VW_CARGA','INT')

Error starting at line : 7 in command -
execute dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'VW_CARGA','INT')
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'GET_DDL' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I must run

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'VW_CARGA','INT') from dual ;
```

Already look at the manuals and found no answer for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory:

```
PLS-00221: 'GET_DDL' is not a procedure or is undefined
```

GET_DDL is not a procedure, its a function that returns a CLOB value.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885

Comment: Thanks Balazs, but in some cases the message isn't 100% accurate, so I doesn't now if it's reliable.